# Missing Vagrant Plugin Pycharm

Tags: vagrant, pycharm

I don't seem to be able to install the vagrant plugin for Pycharm Community 4.5.4. Is this working for anyone? It is supposed to be bundled but it is not. It is also not available from any repo that I can locate.

See attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: And you've followed all steps listed here? https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/configuring_for_vm.html

Comment: Yes. Vagrant is installed and on my path. I simply don't see the plugin being available.

Comment: I'm not even seeing it being available at : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search/index?pr=pycharm&search=vagrant

Comment: can you try download from here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7379?pr=pycharm

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. The error complained saying I needed idea ultimate. I also tried using the professional pycharm version and the vagrant did come bundled/work for the pro version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vagrant plugin depends on the remote interpreter functionality, which is only available in PyCharm Professional. Therefore, the plugin does not work in PyCharm Community Edition.

Comment: Any solution / workaround for PyCharm CE users? Thanks!

Comment: The solution for PyCharm CE users is to use the command line for working with Vagrant.

Comment: What about just putting the project structure in /vagrant ?